# SELECT SQL. Как достать нужную запись из нужного поля

Tags: php, sql, select

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$login' AND password = '$password'"
```

В таблице users, также есть поле  whois, которое принимает два значения: seller or buyer. Как мне построить этот запрос, чтобы он доставал значение из поля whois, соответствующее логину и паролю, в дальнейшем для записи в session.

Comment: "SELECT whois FROM users WHERE login = '$login' AND password = '$password'" это?

Comment: Мне надо значение из поля whois записать в переменную $_SESSION['whois'] = $перменная со значением из поля whois. Не догоняю, как

Comment: Показанный запрос "достаёт" все поля таблицы. В т.ч. и поле whois.

Comment: while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $_SESSION['who'] = $row['whois'];
                echo $_SESSION['who'];}
этого хотел)